# how to add a categories in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the pandas dataframe as below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSm8u.png)

the first set of the Salary , Bonus , Year needs to be tagged to Current, and Second set of columns needs to tagged to Previous. Following is how I wanted to see my dataframe for reporting purposes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEDgh.png)

Can you please advise how I can achieve this solution ?

Tried Categorical column, but unable to come up with the solution required.

Comment: You have to build a MultiIndex